# Measuring time with chrono changes after printing

Tags: c++, performance, c++-chrono

I want to measure the execution time of a program in ns in C++. For that purpose I am using the chrono library.

```
int main() {

    const int ROWS = 200;
    const int COLS = 200;
    double input[ROWS][COLS];
    int i,j;

    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            input[i][j] = i + j;
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto res=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();

    std::cout << "Elapsed time in nanoseconds : "
              << res
              << " ns" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I measured the time and it executed in 90 ns . However when I add a printing afterwards the time changes.

```
int main() {

    const int ROWS = 200;
    const int COLS = 200;
    double input[ROWS][COLS];
    int i,j;

    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            input[i][j] = i + j;
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto res=std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start).count();
    std::cout << "Elapsed time in nanoseconds : "
              << res
              << " ns" << std::endl;

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
            std::cout<<input[i][j];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The time changes to 89700 ns. What could be the problem. I only want to measure the execution time of the for.

Comment: How many times do you run the programs? What is happening with your whole system when you run it? Is the OS or some other process doing something?

Comment: Presumably you are running an optimised build, as the values of `input` are never used in the first example the compiler optimises away all of your code

Comment: What @AlanBirtles said is probably the case. Compare the assembly code between the two and see how the loop in the first case is completely removed: Change the `-O3` to `-O0` and see it pop back: https://godbolt.org/z/QtJhMJ

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Also, since I want to vectorize the code, I am using O3, therefore I want to keep the performance. How to make sure that the compiler always vectorizes my code, although I am using the matrix below afterwards? In the real scenario instead of the matrix iteration I have a matrix multiplication.

Comment: You can't ensure the optimiser does anything. What is happening here isn't the compiler isn't optimising your code in the second case, it is. The issue you are having is the compiler is completely deleting your code in the first case because it doesn't have any noticable effect.